# optimistic locking failure iOS swift

Tags: ios, core-data

Yes of course I did search in the whole internet .
But can't get out of this issue.

I got two entity named:
Post & PopularPost.
(Almost duplicate of one another)

When I fetch the Post and update it's properties like numberoflikes,numberofcomments it's good.

But when I fetch the PopularPost and try to update it's properties then it says 
**"optimistic locking failure"**

MY code to fetch and update and save the entity:"PopularPosts".

```
let postpopFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "PopularPosts")
        postpopFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", postId)
        let resultp = try? CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.fetch(postpopFetch)
        let resultDatap = resultp as! [PopularPosts]

        for object in resultDatap {

            print(object.numberOfHearts)

            if like {
                object.numberOfHearts = object.numberOfHearts + 1
                object.isLiked = true
            }else{
                (object.numberOfHearts > 0) ? (object.numberOfHearts = object.numberOfHearts - 1) : (object.numberOfHearts = 0)
                object.isLiked = false
            }
        }

        do {
            try CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.save()
            print("saved!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

Comment: What does your core-data stack look like? How many contexts do you have? do you have parent child relationships? do you use NSPersistent​Container?

Comment: I got only one context maintained in a singleton class. 
No parent child relationship.

simple 2 entities only.

Comment: Are you always read and writing on the main thread?

Comment: @JonRose:
sometimes background threads are involved

Answer (score 1):

Generally optimistic locking failure is caused by two different managed object contexts trying to change the same data. I think you can also have this issue even with one context if you are inappropriately accessing it from different threads at the same time.  ManagedObjectContexts are **not**
thread safe neither for **reading** or for writing.

I have seen situation that there is access to a managedObjectContext from the wrong thread and there is a crash much later when on a line of code that is doing nothing wrong.  I would recommend to careful search your code for any access to core-data that is not on the main thread.  You use `[NSThread isMainThread]` to check if you are not on the main thread for debugging.

Comment: I got only one managed object contexts 
and
I did checked to ensure access to core data is done from the main thread.

but I am still getting the same issue. 

optmistic locking failure.

How come ??

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by using a `newBackgroundContext()`.

I had a potentially long running task which started when the app went into the background.

Even though it completed before using the app again, I found that all saves made after the background task would fail.

I solved the issue by using the `viewContext` for the long running task.